# How to fix this js code?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I didn't write this code, but I'm still a beginner, can anyone help me with the bugs in this? JSLint kept giving me several bugs and I couldn't seem to fix them. It would be every much appreciated. I'm learning as I post this. I'm currently working on improving my graphic/motion design skills and coding skills. But I can't write something like this currently. If there is anymore detail you need, you can just comment and ask. Thanks.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://209.15.211.170/catalog/", false);
xhr.send();

console.log(xhr.status);
console.log(xhr.statusText);

$("html").html("<h2 style='position:absolute;left:60%;color:#BF34334;font-family:arial;'></h2>");
var minPage = 1;
var maxPage = 12;
var page = minPage;
var json = 'http://209.15.25843811.170/catalog/json?browse&Category=2';
var min = 1;
var max = Number(prompt("Maximum Robux?"));

function buy(item, price) {
    "use strict";
    var link = 'http://209.15.211.170/';
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        var info = (data).find('.ItemSalesTable'.find('.PurchaseButton')).data();
        var buy = 'http://www.roblox.com/API/Item.aspx?rqtype=purchase&productID=' + info[productId] + '&expectedcurrency=1&expectedPrice=' + info[expectedPrice] + '&expectedSellerId=' + info[expectedSellerId] + & userAssetID = +info[userassetId];
        if (parseInt(info) == parseInt(info['expectedPrice'])) {}
    });
}
setInterval(function(3000) {
            function get() {
                    $.get(json, function(Data) {
                            for (var Hat & Data {
                                    if (max >= Price && Price > 0) {
                                        buy(ID, Price)
                                        var dt = new Date();
                                        var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
                                        console.info(Name + '[' + Price + '] @ ' + time);
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                    }
                    get()
                    console.clear();
                    console.info('Running on pages ' + minPage + '-' + maxPage);
                    confirm = function() {};
                    alert = function() {};
                    console.clear();
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Is there more in the script? It looks like the setInterval function doesn't have closing braces

Comment: I'm getting bracket errors and "." errors. What would make the setInterval function complete? If I added the ms?

Comment: http://209.15.211.170/catalog/ doesnt give me anything

Comment: refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: @Ritesh The link is supposed to refer to the IP I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your needs are, but try replacing your code with this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://209.15.211.170/catalog/", false);
xhr.send();

console.log(xhr.status);
console.log(xhr.statusText);

$("html").html("<h2 style='position:absolute;left:60%;color:#BF34334;font-family:arial;'></h2>");
var minPage = 1;
var maxPage = 12;
var page = minPage;
var json = 'http://209.15.25843811.170/catalog/json?browse&Category=2';
var min = 1;
var max = Number(prompt("Maximum Robux?"));

function buy(item, price) {
    "use strict";
    var link = 'http://209.15.211.170/';
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        var info = (data).find('.ItemSalesTable'.find('.PurchaseButton')).data();
        var buy = 'http://www.roblox.com/API/Item.aspx?rqtype=purchase&productID=' + info[productId] + '&expectedcurrency=1&expectedPrice=' + info[expectedPrice] + '&expectedSellerId=' + info[expectedSellerId] + '&userAssetID=' +info[userassetId];
        if (parseInt(info) == parseInt(info['expectedPrice'])) {}
    });
};

function get() {
    $.get(json, function(Data) {
        for (var Hat in Data) {
            if (max >= Price && Price > 0) {
                buy(ID, Price);
                var dt = new Date();
                var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
                console.info(Name + '[' + Price + '] @ ' + time);
            }
        }
    });
};

setInterval(function() {
    get();
    console.clear();
    console.info('Running on pages ' + minPage + '-' + maxPage);
    confirm = function() {};
    alert = function() {};
    console.clear();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: any way can talk to you?